# Custom controller activeadmin with error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am overwriting the create method of activeadmins controller,
I am creating a new user there

```
controller do
  def create
    password_length = 8
    password = Devise.friendly_token.first(password_length)
    local_params = permitted_params[:user].merge(password: password)
    User.create!(local_params)
```

At this point I want to catch any possible errors and expose it to activeadmin new view, what is the proper way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try this:

```
controller do
  def create 
    pwd = Devise.friendly_token.first(8)
    params[:admin_user][:password] = pwd
    super
  end
end
```

Make sure the keys/nesting in the params hash matches the way the `new` form posts them/it. Good luck.